# Dynamically append multiple images

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I have an array of images which I want to merge into 1 using https://github.com/aheckmann/gm.

As the number of elements is not fixed, I am using:

```
var paraArray = [];
.... push the path of the images to the array.
gm('./sprites/tn_1.png').append.apply(this,paraArray)
```

gives the error

> /Users/..../node_modules/gm/lib/args.js:64
>   this.addSrcFormatter(function (src) { ^ TypeError: Object # has no
>   method 'addSrcFormatter' at append
>   (/Users/..../node_modules/gm/lib/args.js:64:12)

If I call

```
gm('./sprites/tn_1.png').append('./sprites/tn_2.png','./sprites/tn_3.png','./sprites/tn_4.png'),
```

it works good. Any idea?

Comment: You should probably use `gm` as first argument to `apply()`, not `this` (either that, or save the return value from `gm()` and use _that_ as first argument).